# How to access a constant defined in another Excel workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

**Question**

How do I access a public constant defined in another Excel workbook?

**Setup**

*Workbook.xls*

My VBA code runs in the current Excel workbook called "MyWorkbook.xls".
It has some VBA code in it which reads a file name --"OtherWorkbook.xls in this case-- from cell "A1". Then, the code should read a constant defined in that other workbook and write it to cell "A2". Here is what my code looks like:

```
Sub GetValueFromOtherWorkbook()
    otherWorkbook = Range("A1").Value  ' Value = "OtherWorkbook.xls"

    Dim returnedValue As String

    ' Idea 1: Doesn't work
    Set returnedValue = OtherWorkbook.xls!Module1.MY_CONSTANT

    ' Idea 2: Doesn't work either
    Set returnedValue = Application.Run(otherWorkbook & "!Module1.MY_CONSTANT")

    Range("A2").Value = returnedValue ' MY_CONSTANT = "testValue"
End Sub
```

*OtherWorkbook.xls*

The second Excel workbook is called "OtherWorkbook.xls" as mentioned above.
It has a VBA module called Module1.
Module1 defines a public constant. The code looks like this:

```
Public Const MY_CONSTANT As String = "testValue"
```

**Problem**

The code from MyWorkbook.xls does not run, it returns the following error

Run-time error '424'

Object required

I don't quite know what to do with it even after reading the help documentation. In another context, I managed to call a routine in another workbook with this code:

```
otherWorkbookName = "OtherWorkbook.xls"
Application.Run (otherWorkbookName & "!Module1.SomeRoutine")
```

So, calling a routine works, but accessing a public constant does not.

Any ideas what I could try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A code module is not an object that can be accessed like a worksheet.

You can access and manipulate it, but in order to do that you need to reference the `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility` library and allow access to the VBA project (Tools - Options - Security - Macro security - Trusted publishers - Trust access to VBA project), after which you can use the `Workbook.VBProject` property of the second workbook.

You don't need to do this. Instead you can create a reference to the other workbook: in VBA IDE, go Tools - References, click `Browse` and locate your workbook with the constant.

If that's no good, you can create a method in that workbook that only returns the value of the constant, and call it as you have demonstrated.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Yes, I also thought of writing a wrapper method as a last resort. I think I'll go with that workaround so I don't have to introduce any new references.